# Extra column looking at where OpenDate > ClosedDate prevoius records

Tags: sql

I have a hard struggle with this problem.

I have the following table:

| TicketNumber | OpenTicketDate YYYY_MM | ClosedTicketDate YYYY_MM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-1 | 2020-1 |
| 2 | 2018-2 | 2021-2 |
| 3 | 2019-1 | 2020-6 |
| 4 | 2020-7 | 2021-1 |

I would like to create an extra column which would monitor the open tickets at the given OpenTicketDate.
So the new table would look like this:

| TicketNumber | OpenTicketDate YYYY_MM | ClosedTicketDate YYYY_MM | OpenTicketsLookingBackwards |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-1 | 2020-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2018-2 | 2021-2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2019-1 | 2020-6 | 3 |
| 4 | 2020-7 | 2021-1 | 2 |

The logic behind the 4th (extra) column is that it looks at the previous records & current record where the ClosedTicketsDate > OpenTicketDate.
For example ticketNumber 4 has '2' open tickets because there are only 2 ClosedTicketDate records where ClosedTicketDate > OpenTicketDate.

The new column only fills data based on looking at **prevoius** records. It is backward looking not forward.

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: line 1 has no record prior so why hasn't it 0

Comment: 1 because 2020-1 is bigger than 2018-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a self join and aggregate as the following:

```
Select T.TicketNumber, T.OpenTicketDate, T.ClosedTicketDate,
  Count(*) as OpenTicketsLookingBackwards
From table_name T Left Join table_name D
On Cast(concat(T.OpenTicketDate,'-1') as Date) < Cast(concat(D.ClosedTicketDate,'-1') as Date)
And T.ticketnumber >= D.ticketnumber
Group By T.TicketNumber, T.OpenTicketDate, T.ClosedTicketDate
Order By T.TicketNumber
```

You may also try with a scalar subquery as the following:

```
Select T.TicketNumber, T.OpenTicketDate, T.ClosedTicketDate,
       (
         Select Count(*) From table_name D 
         Where Cast(concat(T.OpenTicketDate,'-1') as Date) < 
               Cast(concat(D.ClosedTicketDate,'-1') as Date)
         And T.ticketnumber >= D.ticketnumber
        ) As OpenTicketsLookingBackwards
From table_name T 
Order By T.TicketNumber
```

Mostly, joins tend to outperform subqueries.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gRywTFQw).

Comment: Thank you, but just wondering. Is there some window-function also possible?

Comment: You are welcome, do you mean using window function without a self-join?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I think yes; not sure !, but I think it will be less performant , since you have to union all OpenTicketDate with CloseTicketDate, then use conditional window function on that unioned query. I will give it a try and update the answer if succeed.